# How can one perform effective deployment of entity framework 5 on multiple servers

Tags: entity-framework-5

How can one perform effective deployment of entity framework on multiple servers ?

Comment: Can you define effective deployment?

Comment: suppose like i have one console application using/updating a db,another  MVC application using/updating d same db how can i have effectively use Entity framework to access these on multiple servers such that update by one app does not impact d other? hope i m clear , if not please let me know.

Comment: one way i know is using web services is there any other way?